# Make the entries of a matrix positive with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, numerical-linear-algebra

I am considering two slightly more relaxed version of the question asked here: [Making the entries of a matrix positive.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119034/making-the-entries-of-a-matrix-positive)

The two questions are:

**Question 1:**

Consider a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. When does there exist either a matrix $P_M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that
$$
P_M M = \text{abs}(M)
$$
or a matrix $Q_M  \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ such that
$$
M Q_M = \text{abs}(M).
$$
If these matrices exist, how would we compute them?

**NOTE** : by $\text{abs}(M)$ we mean the matrix formed by taking the entry wise absolute value of $M$.

**Question 2**:

Again, consider a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then by $\text{sgn}(M)$ denote the sign pattern matrix of $M$, that is,
$$ [\text{sgn}(M)](i,j) :=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if} M(i,j) < 0,\\
1 & \text{if} M(i,j) > 0,\\
0 & \text{if} M(i,j) = 0,\\
\end{cases}
\ \ \ \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m.  
$$

When does there exist either a matrix $P_M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that
$$
P_M M = \text{sgn}(M)
$$
or a matrix $Q_M  \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ such that
$$
M Q_M = \text{sgn}(M).
$$
These matrices do not necessarily need to be invertible.

**NOTE** : None of the matrices are necessarily invertible.

***EDIT*** : I should note, it would be very nice if a method exists that does not require $\text{abs}(M)$ or $\text{sgn}(M)$ to be computed

Comment: This is very similar to Mike F's answer, but basically, you can reduce to the left case by taking transposes. Then take a subset of the columns of $M$ that is a basis of the column space. We know exactly what the images of these basis vectors must be, so then you can just check if the images we want for the remaining columns agree with the images that have already been determined by linearity. If they do agree, then pick any old $P$ that sends the basis to the right place, which we know exists by extending the basis and using the question you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and an $m$-dimensional column vector $b$, asking whether there is an $n$-dimensional column vector $x$ such that
$$Ax=b$$
is fundamental question in linear algebra. You can use Gaussian elimination to work out whether $b$ is in the column space of $A$ and find a solution vector $x$ in the case that it is.

Seemingly more generally, you could start with $A$ an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ an $m \times k$ matrix and ask whether there exists an $n \times k$ matrix $X$ such that
$$AX=B.$$
This isn't actually a more general question though. You just have to ask the above question $k$ times, once for each column of $B$. As long as all $k$ columns of $B$ belong to the column space of $A$, you just populate the columns of $X$ with any $k$ solution vectors.

It seems to me that your question fits into this framework.

---

**Added:** To spell things out a bit more, given $A$ and $B$, there exists $X$ such that $AX=B$ if and only if the column space of $B$ is contained in the column space of $A$. Similarly (this is the same statement, up to taking the transpose) there exists $X$ such that $XA=B$ if and only if the row space of $B$ is contained in the row space of $A$.

It's not always going to work out that way in the situations you interested in:

Example: The column space of $M=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$ does not contain the column space of $\operatorname{abs}(M) =\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$, so there does not exist $Q_M$ with $MQ_M=\operatorname{abs}(M)$.

Another example: the row space of $M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ does not contain the row space of $\operatorname{sgn}(M)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so there does not exist $P_M$ with $P_MM=\operatorname{sgn}(M)$.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question perfectly! I'm curious, do you know of an algorithmic approach that will decompose M into its positive and negative parts, without iterating over each entry in M?

Comment: I don't and that doesn't really sound possible to me... forming the positive part of $M$ is an entrywise operation, so it shouldn't it require iteration over the entries? Unless there is some extra assumption on $M$.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I don't think it's possible either, but I would love to be wrong.